# Ruby-on-Rails: Multiple has_many :through possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through

Is it possible to have multiple `has_many :through` relationships that pass through each other in Rails?  I received the suggestion to do so as a solution for another question I posted, but have been unable to get it to work.

Friends are a **cyclic association** through a join table.  The goal is to create a `has_many :through` for `friends_comments`, so I can take a `User` and do something like `user.friends_comments` to get all comments made by his friends in a single query.

```
class User
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, 
           :through => :friendships,
           :conditions => "status = #{Friendship::FULL}"
  has_many :comments
  has_many :friends_comments, :through => :friends, :source => :comments
end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
end
```

This looks great, and makes sense, but isn't working for me.  This is the error I'm getting in relevant part when I try to access a user's friends_comments:
`ERROR:  column users.user_id does not exist

: SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"  INNER JOIN "users" ON "comments".user_id = "users".id    WHERE (("users".user_id = 1) AND ((status = 2)))`

When I just enter user.friends, which works, this is the query it executes:
`: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "friendships" ON "users".id = "friendships".friend_id WHERE (("friendships".user_id = 1) AND ((status = 2)))`

So it seems like it's entirely forgetting about the original `has_many` through friendship relationship, and then is inappropriately trying to use the User class as a join table.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

**Edit:**

Rails 3.1 supports nested associations. E.g:

```
has_many :tasks
has_many :assigments, :through => :tasks
has_many :users, :through => :assignments
```

There is no need for the solution given below. Refer to [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/265-rails-3-1-overview) screencast for more details.

**Original Answer**

You are passing a `has_many :through` association as a source for another `has_many :through` 
association. I don't think it will work.

```
  has_many :friends, 
           :through => :friendships,
           :conditions => "status = #{Friendship::FULL}"
  has_many :friends_comments, :through => :friends, :source => :comments
```

You have three approaches to solving this issue.

1) Write an association extension

```
 has_many  :friends, 
           :through => :friendships,
           :conditions => "status = #{Friendship::FULL}" do
     def comments(reload=false)
       @comments = nil if reload 
       @comments ||=Comment.find_all_by_user_id(map(&:id))
     end
 end
```

Now you can get the friends comments as follows:

```
user.friends.comments
```

2) Add a method to the `User` class.

```
  def friends_comments(reload=false)
    @friends_comments = nil if reload 
    @friends_comments ||=Comment.find_all_by_user_id(self.friend_ids)
  end
```

Now you can get the friends comments as follows:

```
user.friends_comments
```

3) If you want this to be even more efficient then:

```
  def friends_comments(reload=false)
    @friends_comments = nil if reload 
    @friends_comments ||=Comment.all( 
             :joins => "JOIN (SELECT friend_id AS user_id 
                              FROM   friendships 
                              WHERE  user_id = #{self.id}
                        ) AS friends ON comments.user_id = friends.user_id")
  end
```

Now you can get the friends comments as follows:

```
user.friends_comments
```

All methods cache the results. If you want to reload the results do the following:

```
user.friends_comments(true)
user.friends.comments(true)
```

OR better still:

```
user.friends_comments(:reload)
user.friends.comments(:reload)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the original purpose behind this approach was so that I could get all of the friends comments from SQL in one query.  See here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382642/ruby-on-rails-how-to-pull-out-most-recent-entries-from-a-limited-subset-of-a-dat

If I write a function, that's going to result in an N+1 number of queries.

Comment: No it will not. It will be 2 queries. First query to get the friends and second query to get the comments for **all** the friends. If you have already loaded the friends to the user model then you are not incurring any cost. I have updated the solution with two more approaches. Take a look.

Comment: @williamjones You don't have N+1 issue in all three approaches. You can check your log file to ensure this. Personally I like approach 1 as it is quite elegant, i.e. `user.friends.comments` is better than `user.friends_comments`

Comment: Could you please explain the argument to find_all_by_users_id in the first solution? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @James: Rails provides two types of dynamic finders: single row (`find_by`) and multi-row(`find_all_by`). The `find_all_by_user_id` is multi-row dynamic finder. Read the rails documentation for more details: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders

Answer (score 8):

There is a plugin that solves your problem, take a look at [this blog](http://kconrails.com/2010/01/28/nesting-has_many-through-relationships-in-ruby-on-rails).

You install the plugin with

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through.git
```

Answer (score 5):

Although this didn't work in the past, it works fine in Rails 3.1 now.

Answer (score 3):

I found this blog entry to be useful:  http://geoff.evason.name/2010/04/23/nested-has_many-through-in-rails-or-how-to-do-a-3-table-join/