# Has a relationship through four models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I'm having trouble setting up this association between my models.

A User has many Accommodations, and Accommodations have one User.

Accommodations have many Notifications, and Notifications have one Accommodation.

Requests have many Notifications.

How can I make it so that I can get all of the Requests for a given User ( that is, User -> Accommodations (each) -> Notification -> Request)?

**Update:**

Here's my current controller file:

```
class PanelController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :login_required

  def index
    @accommodations = current_user.accommodations.all
    @requests = Array.new
    @accommodations.each do |a|
      a.notifications.each do |n|
        @requests << Request.where('id' => n.request_id)
      end
    end

  end

end
```

And models:

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  [snip]
  has_many :accommodations
  has_many :notifications,
           :through => :accommodations
end
```

**models/accommodation.rb**

```
class Accommodation < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title, :description, :thing, :location, :spaces, :price, :photo
  attr_accessible :photo_attributes, :title, :description, :thing, :location, :spaces, :price
  has_one :photo
  has_many :notifications
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photo, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**models/notification.rb**

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :accommodation_id, :request_id
  has_one :request
  belongs_to :accommodation
end
```

**models/request.rb**

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :notifications
  attr_accessible :firstname, :lastname, :email, :phone, :datestart, :dateend, :adults, :children, :location, :status
  validates_presence_of :firstname, :lastname, :email, :phone, :datestart, :dateend, :children, :adults, :location
end
```

Comment: They don't have the associations yet :P I don't think there's anything worth posting. If I'm mistaken let me know and I'll post 'em up!

Comment: When you write "have one", you really mean "belongs_to" right?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
@reqs = []    
@user.accommodations.all.each do |a|
    @reqs << a.notification.request
end
```

Assuming this is correct:

```
class User
    has_many :accommodations
end

class Accommodation
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :notifications
end

class Notification
    belongs_to :accomodation
    belongs_to :request
end

class Request
    has_many :notifications
end
```

---

Using `has_many :through` will not work for multiple models, as seen here: [Ruby-on-Rails: Multiple has_many :through possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383479/ruby-on-rails-multiple-has-many-through-possible)

But you can do something like this in your user model:

```
class User
    has_many :accommodations
    has_many :notifications,
             :through => :accommodations

    def requests 
        self.notifications.all.collect{|n| n.request }
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks codethis. I thought about implementing something along those lines. However, I was told that there is a more "proper" way to do this... Something like has_many :notifications, :through => :accommodations?

Comment: For some reason I'm getting an array returned that looks like this: #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x103221b78>
#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x10320fea0>

Comment: this works for me - can you post your code above?  is it exactly the same?

Comment: I edited my question to include the code. The original error I got from your code was that 'request.notification_id' didn't exist in my table.

Comment: Yes, that works as well. Now the issue is when I use @requests in my view code, I get errors like this: undefined method `firstname' for nil:NilClass. Why is it saying it's a NilClass? It doesn't seem to be accessing, or storing, the data properly in the array.

Comment: what is `@requests.length`?  It seems like you are not returning anything

Comment: I just got it working! Apparently I deleted a notification which got the join table out of sync with everything. Thanks a lot CodeThis, your suggestions were a huge help.