# Rails - "Invalid source reflection" for :has_many => :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having a problem with an `:has_many => :through` association which references another `:has_many => :through` association.

I have a `User`->`Cart`->`CartItem`->`Product` model setup going in my rails application. Here are the model associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases,  :class_name => "Cart",
                        :dependent => :destroy,
                        :conditions => {:purchased => true}
  has_many :items,      :through => :purchases,
                        :readonly => true
  has_many :products,   :through => :purchases,
                        :readonly => true
end

class Cart < Activerecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items,    :class_name => "CartItem",
                      :dependent => :delete_all                 
  has_many :products, :through => :items
end

class CartItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :product
end
```

The idea is that a cart has many cart_items, which are just references to existing products. After a cart is marked as purchase, a user should have access to products directly via `user.products`.

Anyway... I can not figure out how to setup my `User` model so that the relationship is possible. I keep getting the following error:

```
Invalid source reflection macro :has_many :through for has_many :products,
:through => :purchases. Use :source to specify the source reflection.
```

I'm assumming it wants me to add a `:source` attribute to the `has_many :products` assoc. in the User model, but that seems silly considering the source association is named identically (and it doesn't work when I add `:source => :products` anyway).

Does anyone know how I could get this to work? I'd really appreciate any suggestions!

Sorry if this question has been asked before, but I've been searching and I can't find an answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby-on-Rails: Multiple has_many :through possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383479/ruby-on-rails-multiple-has-many-through-possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails won't allow you chain nested `has_many :through` associations like that.

There's a similar question here: [Ruby-on-Rails: Multiple has_many :through possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383479/ruby-on-rails-multiple-has-many-through-possible)

Comment: I've set up an instance method that basically does what I wanted it to (based on the post you pointed to). Thanks a ton for link, didn't know this was a problem.

Comment: As of rails 3 i believe this is possible

Comment: I'm currently upgrading an app from Rails 2.3 (I know) to, eventually, Rails 4.2.5. I'm currently on the Rails 3.0 release and am stuck with this same problem. But yes, I know that in the last 3 release, you can chain has_many :throughs