# Problem sorting an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm mixing 2 arrays and want to sort them by their created_at attribute:

```
@current_user_statuses = current_user.statuses
@friends_statuses = current_user.friends.collect { |f| f.statuses }
@statuses = @current_user_statuses + @friends_statuses
@statuses.flatten!.sort!{ |a,b| b.created_at <=> a.created_at }
```

The `@current_user_statuses` and `@friends_statuses` each sort correctly, but combined they sort incorrectly, with the `@friends_statuses` always showing up on top sorted by their `created_at` attribute and the `@current_user_statuses` on the bottom sorted by their `created_at` attribute.

This is the view:

```
<% @statuses.each do |d| %>
<%= d.content %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm really struggling to understand what the problem is. Would you mind rephrasing the text after the first code sample?

Comment: "the friends statuses always showing up on the top sorted by there created at attribute and the current_user_statuses in the bottem sorted by there created at attribute" --- and the times in created_at suggest that the records should be intermingled?

Comment: @gal, please show the desired result. Thanks.

Comment: Post an example output, so we can see the dates.  Have you checked to make sure they're not just coincidentally ordered this way?

Comment: Unless you show a good sample of the data being tested, we can't help you further. Telling everyone who has answered "the sorting is not my problem... my friends statuses always showing up in the top" does not help. Take the time to provide a full data sample.

Comment: Change your view code to print the created_at dates so that we, and you, can see them. All of the sorting approaches suggested on this page will intermingle the `@current_user_statuses` and `@friends_statuses` assuming that created_at dates are intermingled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
(current_user.statuses + current_user.friends.collect(&:statuses)) \
  .flatten.compact.sort_by(&:created_at)
```

Comment: the sorting is not my problem... my friends statuses always showing up in the top...

Answer (score 1):

You can not daisy chain the `flatten!` method like that. `flatten!` returns nil if no changes were made to the array. When you sort nil nothing will happen.

You need to separate them:

```
@statuses.flatten!
@statuses.sort! { ... }
```

Comment: Quite true, though this isn't really an answer to the question ;)  When you sort nil, you'll get `NoMethodError`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

Set up the classes:

```
class User

  class Status
    attr_reader :statuses, :created_at
    def initialize(stats)
      @statuses = stats
      @created_at = Time.now
    end
  end

  attr_reader :statuses, :friends
  def initialize(stats=[], friends=[])
    @statuses = Status.new(stats)
    @friends = friends
  end
end
```

Define some instances, with some time gaps just for fun:

```
friend2 = User.new(%w[yellow 2])
sleep 1
friend1 = User.new(%w[orange 1])
sleep 2
current_user = User.new(%w[green 1], [friend1, friend2])
```

Here's how I'd do it differently; Get the statuses in `created_at` order:

```
statuses = [
  current_user.statuses, 
  current_user.friends.collect(&:statuses)
].flatten.sort_by(&:created_at)
```

Which looks like:

```
require 'pp'
pp statuses

# >> [#<User::Status:0x0000010086bd60
# >>   @created_at=2011-07-02 10:49:49 -0700,
# >>   @statuses=["yellow", "2"]>,
# >>  #<User::Status:0x0000010086bc48
# >>   @created_at=2011-07-02 10:49:50 -0700,
# >>   @statuses=["orange", "1"]>,
# >>  #<User::Status:0x0000010086bb30
# >>   @created_at=2011-07-02 10:49:52 -0700,
# >>   @statuses=["green", "1"]>]
```

I'm just building a temporary containing array to hold the current_user's status, plus the status of all the friends, then flattening it.

The `(&:statuses)` and `(&:created_at)` parameters are Rails short-hand for the `statuses` method of the instance, or `created_at` method of the instance.

Comment: the sorting is not my problem... my friends statuses always showing up in the top...

Comment: Actually, sorting is a problem in your code. You're using `sort` instead of `sort_by` which is significantly slower when dealing with data structures or objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
@statuses = (@current_user_statuses + @friends_statuses).sort_by(&:created_at)
```

Comment: the sorting is not my problem... my friends statuses always showing up in the top...

Comment: Please prove that by providing the output of `p statuses.map(&:created_at)`

Answer (score 0):

I know there are several solutions posted for your question. But all of these solutions can kill your system when the number of statuses grow in size. For this dataset, you have to perform the sorting and pagination in the database layer and NOT in the Ruby layer

**Approach 1: Simple and concise**

```
Status.find_all_by_user_id([id, friend_ids].compact, :order => :created_at)
```

**Approach 2: Long and efficient**

```
class User    
  def all_statuses
    @all_statuses ||=Status.all( :joins => "JOIN (
        SELECT friend_id AS user_id 
        FROM   friendships 
        WHERE  user_id = #{self.id}
      ) AS friends ON statuses.user_id = friends.user_id OR 
                      statuses.user_id = {self.id}",
      :order => :created_at
    )
  end    
end
```

Now you can get the sorted statuses in single query:

```
user.all_statuses
```

**PPS:** If this is my code I would further optimize the SQL. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383479/ruby-on-rails-multiple-has-many-through-possible/2383560#2383560) for some more details.

Comment: the sorting is not my problem... my friends statuses always showing up in the top...

Comment: If you use the method I have suggested, this can only happen ONLY if the friend's statuses are newer than your statuses.