# How to traverse multiple many to many associations in activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I am building a authorization framework that will eventually use cancan at the code level. I am creating the model and associations and have things almost perfect, but I ran into a snag.

I have User, Roles and Rights with many to many join tables (user_roles and role_rights) and I have things setup so that you can do User.roles and User.roles.first.rights but I would like to be able to do User.rights

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, :through => :user_roles
end

class UserRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, :through => :users_roles
  has_many :role_rights
  has_many :rights, :through => :role_rights
end

class RoleRight < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :right
end

class Right < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :role_rights
  has_many :roles, :through => :role_rights
end
```

The following works:

```
User.roles
```

so does this:

```
User.roles.first.rights
```

but what I want to do is:

```
User.rights
```

but when I try, I get the follow error: NoMethodError: undefined method `rights'

I assume that I need to add something to the User model to let it transverse to the Right model but I can't figure out the associations.

I'm using Rails 2.3.4 and Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: The association methods works on an model instance rather than a model class. OTH, what are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: Nested `has_many :through` is not supported in rails 2.3.x( it is supported in Rails 3.1 and above). Refer to this answer(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383479/ruby-on-rails-multiple-has-many-through-possible/2383560#2383560) to find out how you can support it in Rails 2.3.x.

Comment: did you try the proposed solution? Look after the questions you make!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.rights
     Right.joins(:roles => :user).all("users.id = ?", self.id)
   end
end
```

Comment: +1 Nested `has_many` work in Ruby 3, but AFAIK this is the only approach in Rails 2.