# Modeling Relationships with Four or More Models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these models in my Rails app:

```
group.rb
  has_many :group_members
  has_many :group_foo_types


group_member.rb
  # fields
  :group_id, :user_id 

  belongs_to:group
  has_many :group_foo_types, :through=>:groups
  has_one :user
  has_many :foo, :through=>:user
  has_many :bar, :through=>:user


group_foo_type.rb
  # fields
  :group_id, :foo_type_id

  belongs_to :group    
  belongs_to :foo_type


user.rb
  has_many :foo
  has_many :bar


foo.rb
  # fields
  :user_id, :foo_type_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :foo_type


bar.rb
  # fields
  :user_id, :foo_type_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :foo_type
```

What I'm trying to do is, for a group, find the foos and bars per user taking into account the foo_type_id for the group (from group_foo_type).

However, I'm not sure if I have this modeled correctly.

From this, it seems like I can do `group.group_members.user` to get the users and then `user.foos' and 'user.bars` to get a user's foos and bars.  This doesn't take into account the `foo_type_id` for the `group` though (from `group_foo_type`).

Can someone please help recommend an approach to accomplish what I want to do?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2383560/137211), since Rails 3.1 you can nest `has_many :through` associations. So to have easy access to all of a group's foos and bars, you could add the following associations:

```
# group.rb
has_many :users, through: :group_members
has_many :foos, through: :users
has_many :bars, through: :users
```

With this, `group.foos` would give you all of the group's foos (via `group_member` and `user`).

The association methods in rails can be used with the various finder methods, so to limit the foos by `group_foo_type`:

```
group_foos = group.foos.where(foo_type_id: group.group_foo_type_ids)
```

(`group_foo_type_ids` being another useful association method, check the [Association Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference) guide for more info.)

**A caution**: there are a lot of steps that have to go on in the background to achieve any of this stuff, even if it does get relatively easy to actually code. You may want to keep an eye on the queries that get generated (either through the console or logs) and how they perform, as they're likely to get fairly involved. It looks like you have a fairly complex set of associations there, so it may be worth looking at whether you can simplify anything there. Just something to keep in mind!