# Loopback how to set up nested relations

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, loopbackjs

I'm playing with **Strongloop Loopback** lately (ie: http://loopback.io/), it's a fantastic tool. I went through their sample cases and it works just great.

But this is basic examples ; based on simple data models as below (which is fine to start):

[image: example]

**ORIGINAL SAMPLE**

Now, if you think about a slightly more complicated data model... let say a data model about comics (http://developer.marvel.com/docs), where you have various series which are made up of several comics, and within comics you have many characters.

**UPDATE: added a sub-series model between series and comics**

If I translate this in loopback relations:

```
Serie hasMany Sub-series
Sub-series belongsTo a Serie
Sub-serie hasMany Comics
Comic belongsTo a Sub-serie
Comic hasMany Characters
Character belongsTo a Comic
```

Here is my issue, **how to get all characters for a given serie? How should I describe this relation**.

Comment: did you find a solution? I need to do the same and populate nested models

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`hasMany through`](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/defining-and-mapping-data-relations-with-loopback-connected-models/).

What about something like this:

```
Serie.hasMany(Character, {through: Comic});
```

Comment: Yes, I agreed with that, my sample case was not relevant... :)
What's about nested relations with more levels (updated my sample case)?

Answer (score 0):

See this example for relation examples: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-relations-basic

Comment: I have seen this example, but I don't answer my problem. I'm talking about nested relations (more than 1 level). Loopback doesn't seem to support multiple hasMany:through relations.

Similar problem here with Ruby: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383479/ruby-on-rails-multiple-has-many-through-possible